# Sync the threaded execution of two methods in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Using Qt, I have two instances of a `Worker` class (which inherits `QObject`), each of which lives in its own thread by using `moveToThread`.

The `Worker` class has a `performOperation` method that I call from my main thread using:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(workerLeft, "performOperation");
```

so that it runs in the worker's thread. That's nice, but I want to run `performOperation` on my two instances of `Worker` in parallel, and wait in my main thread for both to finish. Something like having a `BlockingQueuedConnection` in parallel.

I have tried a different strategy, using `QtConcurrent::run` and `QFutureSynchronizer`, like this:

```
QFuture<QString> runLeft = QtConcurrent::run(workerLeft, &Worker::performOperation);
QFuture<QString> runRight = QtConcurrent::run(workerRight, &Worker::performOperation);

QFutureSynchronizer<QString> sync;
sync.addFuture(runLeft);
sync.addFuture(runRight);

sync.waitForFinished();
```

But it doesn't work because I'm using a `QTcpSocket` in my `Worker` that I work with in `performOperation` and it fails with:

```
QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread
```

I've been able to make it work by creating the `QTcpSocket` in the `performOperation` method but I don't like that, it's pretty expensive to create the socket every time.

I think I could achieve it if I could choose which thread the `QtConcurrent::run` should run in, but I haven't found any similar option.

Comment: you can emit signal from your worker, and in slot you check if you received two signals, perform your operation and set counter to 0.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I want to block the main thread right after the two calls, that's why I don't consider using signals and manually carrying a counter.

Comment: Without `QtConcurrent` how do worker thread finishes? does it signal?

Comment: I manually handle the quitting and deletion of the thread at program end.

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino, Sorry Confused .. you said _... wait in my main thread for both to finish_ .. Anyway I was thinking of a local Eventloop.

Comment: For both _performOperation methods_, not for both threads.

Comment: A socket must live in the thread that works with it. How do you create it? Is it an outbound connection or inbound (through QTcpServer)? Why can't you create it in the worker?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion :
1/  if you use QtConcurrent, basically you let Qt managing every stuff related to multithreading. In this case uou do not create a worker thread manually at any point neither you move the object to this worker, see the doc :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html

The contract is simply to pass a (staless) function that will be executed in a background thread. It's a high level parallel programming API.

2/ If you implement a worker object which lives in a worker thread, and you want to synchronise , you must use other methods, like signal/slots for example or QMutex. It's a lower level threading API and it is not meant to work in conjunction with the Concurrent and Future API.